# Multivariate version of Weil's bound?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, characters

Let $\chi$ be the quadratic residue character in $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is a prime such that $q \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 4)}$, defined by
\begin{align*}
\chi(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0, & \text{if $x=0$}, \\
1, & \text{if $x \neq 0$ is a quadratic residue in $\mathbb{F}_q$}, \\
-1, & \text{otherwise}. \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}

It is known, through Weil's bound, that for any degree-$d$ polynomial $P(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ that is not in the form $P(x) = Q^2(x)$ for another polynomial $Q$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_q} \chi\left( P(x)\right) \leq (d-1) \sqrt{q}.
\end{align*}

I have a character sum in the form
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\left(x_1,\dots,x_k\right) \in \mathbb{F}_q^k} \chi\left( (x_1 - x_2)(x_2 - x_3)\dots(x_k - x_1)\right).
\end{align*}

Is there a multivariate version of Weil's bound that can work here?

I thought that perhaps the isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}_q^k$ and the extension field $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ can be used to map this character sum to the setup of Weil's bound, but I don't know much about finite fields, so I am not sure if when we treat $\left(x_1,\dots,x_k\right)$ as an element of $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$, what's inside $\chi(\cdot)$ can still be considered a polynomial.

Comment: What is the actual formula/pattern  giving your product  $(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)\cdots (x_k-x_1)$?  Is it a product like $\prod \limits_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$?

Comment: I have a $q\times q$ matrix $A$ whose $(i,j)$th element is $\chi(i-j)$, and this sum appears by expanding $\text{trace}\left( A^k\right)$.

Comment: So is $q$ a prime number?

Comment: Yes, sorry just edited the question.

Comment: So you have some sort of circulant matrix $A$, and you want to investigate  the quadratic residue of the elements in the main diagonal of $A^k$, right?
Do you have any condition on $k$? like  $p\nmid k$, or something?